# Why does Python re finditer() group() attribute only return matches on first call in interpreter?

Tags: python, regex

Can anyone explain why print match.group() only returns the resulting matches the first time it is called in a for loop below? I would expect it to print the matches every time it is called. I encountered this example while going through [this section](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#performing-matches) in Python Docs: Regex HOWTO

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('\d+')
>>> iterator = p.finditer('12 drummers, 11 pipers, 10 dancers')
>>> iterator
<callable-iterator object at 0x107deabd0>
>>> for match in iterator:
...  print match.group()
... 
12
11
10
>>> for match in iterator:
...  print match.group()
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the behavior described by the python [documentation for `iterator`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).

Quoting the docs:

> The intention of the protocol is that once an iterator’s next() method 
>   raises StopIteration, it will continue to do so on subsequent calls. 
>   Implementations that do not obey this property are deemed broken.

You read all the items in the iterator in the first `for ... in` loop, so there is nothing left to read.

If you want to go through the matches again, you'll need to get a new iterator:

```
>>> iterator = p.finditer('12 drummers, 11 pipers, 10 dancers')
```

Comment: if you are repeatedly using the matches maybe use re.findall: >>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('\d+')
>>> mylist = p.findall('12 drummers, 11 pipers, 10 dancers')
>>> print mylist
['12', '11', '10']
>>>

Answer (score 2):

`p.finditer()` returns an iterator which yields the matches. Once the iterator is run all the way through once, the iterator is exhausted. It's the same as if you do this:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> it = iter(l)
>>> for val in it:
    print val
1
2
3
>>> for val in it:
    print val
>>>
```

That is, you're never calling `match.group()` in the second for loop. If you were, and it didn't return anything, you should instead have expected to see some `None`s printed out.

Comment: Had to give this one to @Carl because he cited his answer from the Python docs. Gave you an upvote for being first though.

Comment: @JamesNicholson: sure thing, thanks. good to know that it is specified behavior